# Symfony 2.1 + @MongoDBUnique(fields="email") not unique

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to use **MongoDB** with **Symfony2.1** but I'm facing a problem.
I'm following the [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/form.html) from Symfony website called "*How to implement a simple Registration Form with MongoDB*".

In this tutorial, it is said that we can add a constraint on email field as a unique field.
After some tests, it doesn't work. I can add more than once the same email for my User entity.

The annotation *@MongoDBUnique(fields="email")* seems to fail.

I found someone which has the same [problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/doctrine-dev/yxPtk-gRghw) in a Google Group. At this time (posted on january, 6th), no one has answered or no one seems to have any answer unfortunelately.

Thanks for any clue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that index really exists in MongoDb. The specified annotation doesn't create any index automatically.

For more information check [this](http://www.testically.org/2011/08/25/using-a-unique-index-in-mongodb-with-doctrine-odm-and-symfony2/).

Comment: Thank you for this link ! It works now thanks to you, an exception occurred when email already in database.

Comment: I finally only need this annotation : @ODM\String @ODM\Index(unique=true, order="asc")